# Powershell - Export structure of folders to txt or xls but only to a depth of 3 folders and no files

Tags: powershell, structure, directory

I am looking to export a folder structure from a server and it's kind of huge.
So I am looking to narrow the list to a depth of 3 folders max and show no files. So actually I have a part of the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/258287/how-can-i-export-a-directory-structure?newreg=e3bcf7f69d94442190cb75b74eff33bb) already using Get-ChildItem.
But I am missing the parameter to narrow down the list.
Any idea ?

Thanks

EDIT: Export to a text file or excel sheet - No robocopy

Comment: What kind or output file you are after? A graphical directory tree? Just a list of subdirectories? Something you can process later automatically?

Comment: The goal is to have a file I can give my customer so he has an overview of the structure and can tell what permission on which folder he wants. So I can manage it accordinly afterwards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `-Directory` flag to get only folders, `-Recurse` to include subfolders, and `-Depth` to control how far down to go. `0` is current directory folders, `1` includes their subfolders etc.

You can combine with `Select-Object` to specify the properties to select, and `Export-Csv` or `Out-File` to create a csv/txt file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Depth 3 |
    Select-Object FullName |
    Export-Csv Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

<sub>**Ref:** [Get-ChildItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem),
 [Select-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object), [Export-Csv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)</sub>

Comment: Thanks this is great. THere is just one more thing I would like to do. So I used your script but I just asked names instead of fullname.
But the Depth parameter puts the subfolders on the bottom and not in order... is there anyway powershell could show them in the correct order ?

Comment: @RazZ - **For Name:** `Select-Object Name` instead of `Select-Object FullName` **For sorting:** Check out [`Sort-Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object). Give it a go, search around here and the internet. If you still have problems, please post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help =)

Comment: Powershell 5.0 or above is needed (!)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for Powershell scripting, as [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) is part of default install in newer Windows versions. It supports copying partial directory trees. The switch `/lev:<N>` copies only the top N levels of the source directory tree.

Additional switches like `/e` (empty directories) and `/xf *` (exclude all files) are useful to copy just the directory structure.

Comment: Well, I'd like to avoid the need to actually copy something, for example, if I'm to process the list of dirs programmatically. However, if "export"=="copy elsewhere", this is the solution.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I meant export to a text or excel file. The goal is to have a written structure. Thanks anyways